# How to enable co-authoring on a SharePoint wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wiki-pages, co-authoring

I am trying to implement co-authoring for a SharePoint wiki library.

I have configured versioning and the other prerequisites are met as stated at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249.aspx

My questions are:

1. Is this possible OOB? If yes, how?
2. In case it is not possible using SharePoint OOB features, how can we do it programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

According to this site https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718249(v=office.16).aspx, it is not possible OOT.

> Office provides co-authoring functionality for Word, PowerPoint, OneNote, and Visio. If you are using SharePoint Online or have SharePoint Server 2013 configured to use Office Web Apps Server, users can also co-author documents in **Word, PowerPoint, Excel, and OneNote Web Apps**.

If you really want to implement that you need to use event receiver that will capture event itemupdating and combine changes made from user.
[Creating Simple Event Receiver in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Ariwi! Any article relevant to implementing this using event receiver would be much appreciated :)